# Smartphone use among visually impaired person: A report of two cases study or two case studies

Tags: word-choice, difference

> A report of **two cases study** OR ***two case studies***

in the above, which one will be correct or appropriate?

Comment: [Case study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_study) is a compound noun, so the whole thing is pluralised - _case studies_.

Answer (score 1):

It is "two case studies", as there are "two studies" and the "studies" are actually "case studies". If you wanted "case" to be plural, you'd have to say:

> A report of two cases was found ...

> "Case study" is a compound noun, so the whole thing is pluralised - case studies - @KateBunting